# How is an index of n=0 possible for the Lane-Emden equation?

Tags: the-sun, astrophysics, mathematics

I was recently showing that an index of $n=0$ for the [Lane-Emden equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lane%E2%80%93Emden_equation) results in constant density throughout the star. However, in my calculations I had to use the constant $\alpha$ which can be defined as $$\alpha = \frac{r}{\xi}$$ or $$\alpha = \sqrt{\frac{(n+1)K\rho_c^{\frac{1}{n}-1}}{4\pi G}}.$$
Now, using the first expression works perfectly but I just noticed that the second expression breaks down as $n=0$. So how can it still be a solution to Lane-Emden? Do we use some kind of $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow 0}$ technique or how is this issue resolved?

Comment: Have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lane–Emden_equation ?  There appears to be a special case in the derivation for n=0

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome I have read it multiple times but cant seem to spot a remark to the porblem. It solves the Equation for $n=0$ but does not use $\alpha$ in the context of the solution.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lane%E2%80%93Emden_equation#For_n_=_0